# Text to columns date formatting issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently having an issue trying to get a column which contains time and date minutes and seconds info to be reformatted into a time and date format I can then use with the filters to re-order oldest to newest etc.

here is an example of the cell entry

```
24/03/2021 10:30:35:540
```

Now, if I use the Macro recorder to record me selecting the desired column and using text to columns feature > Fixed width, take the column break line to 16 and select General for column data format, I end up with the cell entry as this below, which works with filtering.

```
24/03/2021  10:30:00 AM
```

once stop recording the Macro and review I get this below in VBA:

```
Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("P1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

My issues is, when I try to run this code as a macro, it affects the dates, see explanation below, it seems to only affect dates where the format can be swapped to Americanised?

so for example original cell contains 7th March 2021

```
07/03/2021 05:46:45:328
```

When manually using text to columns, its ok, but when using VBA running above code, date and month transposes, below is results split into two columns, 3 and 7 have swapped, and now date is 3rd July

```
3/07/2021 5:46  :45:328
```

I don't really need to use text to columns feature if I don't have to, but having trouble getting the cell to convert to date and time format without it.

For example have also tried `=LEFT(P2,16)` then re-pasted the columns as values then tried to use format cells > custom > `d/mm/yyyy h:mm`, but that didn't work.

if anyone has any other suggestions I'm keen to hear?, hoping to be able to run something through VBA as part of a larger set of Macro's to focus is to be able to get it done via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Array(0, 1)` to `Array(1,4)` for `DMY`

If you record the macro with the below setting you will get the above code.

[image]

Also you do not need to [SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) the column. Try this

```
Columns("P:P").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("P1"), _
DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,4), Array(16, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

**Note**: This unfortunately is not 100% reliable. VBA is "very US-centric" :D

Comment: Have just changed it and it seems to retain the same issue where it transposes the date around, it also looked to have cut too much from the hh:mm details as well, may be due to how the dates are entered with no 0 for first 9 days of month just 7/3/2021.

Comment: Format the columns and then use `.TextToColumns`. See if that helps?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for the extra suggestion, looks to still revert back to usa format even with a format change prior to running the text to cols VBA macro, thanks for assistance and hints anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Power Query solution (and, if your data is originally coming from a CSV file, this algorithm could be incorporated and used as part of your import procedure).

- Retain the fractional seconds by replacing the final colon with a decimal:

  - Split on the last `:` colon

[image]

- Then Merge (rejoin) using the `.` decimal as the separator

[image]

- Change data type **using locale** and selecting something like `English(European)` and `datetime`

  - *Access this dialog from right click on the column*

[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Timestamp", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({":"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Timestamp.1", "Timestamp.2"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(
            Table.TransformColumnTypes(
                #"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Timestamp.2", type text}}, "en-US"),
                    {"Timestamp.1", "Timestamp.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.None),"Timestamp"),
    
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"Timestamp", type datetime}}, "en-150")
in
    #"Changed Type with Locale"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your suggestion, will give it a go when I get the chance and see how it goes!